# How to open an app in splitview content area?

Tags: c#, uwp

I basially want to open an app within my project directory into the splitview content area.
**XAML**

```
        <SplitView x:Name="MainPanel" DisplayMode="Inline" IsPaneOpen="True">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <NavigationView x:Name="Navigation" SelectionChanged="Navigation_Navigate">
                    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="Home" Icon="Home" Content="Home"/>
                        <NavigationViewItem x:Name="Colours" Icon="Edit" Content="Colours"/>
                        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Admin" Content="Security"/>
                        <NavigationViewItem Icon="World" Content="Translate"/>
                    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
                </NavigationView>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Button Background="Green"/>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
private async void NavigateToApp()
        {
            var NextPage = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int NewViewID = 0;
            
            if (!IsOpen)
            {
                await NextPage.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    Frame NewFrame = new Frame();
                    NewFrame.Navigate(typeof(Colours), null);


                    Window.Current.Content = NewFrame;
                    
                    Window.Current.Activate();

                    MainPanel.Content = NewFrame;

                    NewViewID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                });
                
                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(NewViewID, ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);

                IsOpen = true;
            }
            
                //IsOpen = false;
            
            //await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(NewViewID, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
            
        }
        #region Test
        
        private void Navigation_Navigate(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                switch (item.Content)
                {
                    case "Home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "Colours":
                        NavigateToApp();
                        break;

                    case "Translate":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Translate));
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

This is how i intended for the app to work:
-User click button on Navigation menu item(s), e.g. Colours
-Then colours page is loaded into a new frame, then new frame into window, then window into splitview.content

Comment: SplitView is native UWP, not Xamarin

Comment: ok, thanks for the correction, do you know how to put a new app into a uwp splitview content area by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can only set the `Content` property of a `SplitView` to a `UIElement` and a `Window` is not a `UIElement`.

What you should do is to move the *contents* of the app window into a `UserControl` or similar and set the `Content` property to an instance of this one.

You cannot display a top-level window or an entire app inside another control.